# left join like I'm want if table don't have value but if have value returned empty result

Tags: mysql

I have query like this

```
 select absen.*,karyawan.* from karyawan left join absen on 
karyawan.id_kar=absen.id_kar where tgl=curdate() or tgl is null
```

it's success return although table absen don't have value 
[image]

but when table absen have value like this

[image]

result MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: today is 2016-10-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is since you have used column belongs to left joined table in the where clause. This is kind of some wired behavior. Please move those filters to join and that should work.

```
select absen.*,karyawan.* from karyawan left join absen on 
karyawan.id_kar=absen.id_kar and tgl=curdate() or tgl is null
```

Comment: or tgl is null is not necessary, nulls will be included because of left join.

Comment: Yes you can remove that too

Comment: thans you helped me :)